# How to log when a a connection to the database is restored in Talend?

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend, tJDCBConnection.
Before running a db actions I added the tJDCBConnection component so if the connection was lost it will be reconnected again.

How can I tell if the connection was re-established so I can add a log message?

Thank you,
Shirly

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt this schema `tJDBCConnection-->onComponentOK-->tWarn`.
As soon as the tJDBCConnection is called, tWarn send the message you've configured.
In parallel, you need a tLogCatcher to catch all messages issued from tWarn (and/or tDie and/or Java exceptions) and log these messages in the desired logfile.

Hope this helps,
TRF